# How to send HTML code in an http POST request?

Tags: php, html, http, post

I am an sending a HTTP POST request from a Google Web Toolkit app to a php script. The content-type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" right now so I can send variables to php and use `$_POST[]` in php but I don't think I can properly send HTML markup inside one of the variables.

Here's what I have: 
    `post_data = var1=true&var2=true$html="HTML MARKUP HERE"`

When doing it this way barely any of the html comes through to php in the `$_POST['html']` variable.  What is the proper method to accomplish sending html markup in a POST variable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the query parameter. In JavaScript, you can use [the `encodeURIComponent` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: Great!! That's what I needed!  Just to add more to this discussion...Use the PHP function rawurldecode() to decode the encoded html back into regular html markup.

Comment: Thank you, I just accepted the answer.  Sorry for the 8 year delay!!