# Decode HTML back to original HTML code in PHP POSTed by JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, urlencode

There is a question on SO [How to send HTML code in an http POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204439/how-to-send-html-code-in-an-http-post-request) and works good in sending but receiving of HTML and decode it back to original HTML is not working

My HTML Code as

```
<div id="TypePostBox">
   <div style='margin-top:20px;'>Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Currently I am posting with JQuery with this code as suggested in above link

```
var cod = encodeURIComponent($('#TypePostBox').html());
//code to POST with jquery
console.log(cod);
//Output in console as %26lt%3Bdiv%20style%3D'margin-top%3A20px%3B'%26gt%3BHello%20World%26lt%3B%2Fdiv%26gt%3B
```

and receiving it in php as

```
echo rawurldecode($_POST['dt']);
//PHP Output as &lt;div style='margin-top:20px;'&gt;Hello World&lt;/div&gt;
```

How can I send and get the exact HTML Code? I want to POST not GET with Jquery / Javascript. I am ajaxing it.

I just want to send exact HTML and receive exact HTML, What can be done?

Comment: it's already encoded on the client-side, so you're encoding it yet again, which means you have to decode it TWICE in php. e.g. `rawurldecode(rawurldecode($your_html))`

Comment: If I do not encode it on client side then PHP cannot receive it but a null value is sent by Javascript

Comment: so just decode it twice and move on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure

```php
echo html_entity_decode(rawurldecode($_POST['dt']));
```

does the job. See **[html_entity_decode**](https://www.php.net/en/html_entity_decode).

Comment: Thanks buddy. Is there any shorter way to send and receive exact HTML in php and javascript other than this?

Comment: I am afraid not. You could find a javascript library that MD5 the string, for instance, and then unpack serverside - but this would be more expensive.

Comment: OK this works fine. I just replaced html_entity_decode with htmlspecialchars_decode for better performance as I made few Benchmarks and htmlspecialchars is about 40% faster then others.

Answer (score 0):

Post an echo of the post['dt'] with out using the rawurldecode